# How to use multiprocessing in Python with Django to create thousands of model instances from xml file?

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a script that parses data from an `xml` file into Django models. It works ok but recently we've been encountering files with dozen of thousands of models to create which is incredibly slowing down the process (up to 40 min to upload a single 20MB file).

I would like to try and use `multiprocessing` to speed it up as much as I can but I am new to this package. This is the current setup:

- `create_profiles_from_xml`: is a function that loops through the data extracted from the `xml`, called `xml_members`, popping one element at a time (it has to be like that due to a relationship that can be created with the next element or not).
- `create_profile`: is a just a function that handles the data to match with the model fields and then call the `.create()` method, that's why I omitted the details of this function here.

```py
def create_profiles_from_xml(xml_members, device):
    profiles = []

    while len(xml_members) > 0:
        parent_member = members.pop(0)
        profile = create_profile(parent_member, parent=None)
        if profile:
            profiles.append(profile)

    return profiles
```

- And here is what I tried to do with the multipocessing

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def create_profiles_from_xml(xml_members, device):
    profiles = []

    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    profiles = pool.imap_unordered(create_profile, xml_members)
                
    return profiles
```

And everytime I try to run it I get this error traceback:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 223, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/axes/middleware.py", line 49, in __call__
    failures_since_start = AxesProxyHandler.get_failures(request, credentials)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/axes/handlers/proxy.py", line 94, in get_failures
    return cls.get_implementation().get_failures(request, credentials)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/axes/handlers/database.py", line 75, in get_failures
    attempt_count = max(
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/axes/handlers/database.py", line 77, in <genexpr>
    attempts.aggregate(Sum("failures_since_start"))[
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 379, in aggregate
    return query.get_aggregation(self.db, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 489, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1140, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/omnio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 223, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relationship between elements and why it means you have to extract one at a time? Using bulk_create to reduce everything to a single DB call would be ideal if possible, can you share your model and maybe an example of a some of the data?

Comment: The model is quite long, to be honest, we can't use bulk_create because each element extracted from the xml can have different formats that's why we have to handle one by one. And the relationship is what we call parent-children (M2M with itself in the model) where a parent can have multiple children that are objects of the same model but with completely different data. And children can have more children and so on...

Comment: How many elements are there? If `create_profile` relies on data from the previous element then I'm not sure how you would split this into multiple processes as they may depend on something done in a different process? You can handle the different formats be cleaning the data before appending to the bulk_create list

Comment: Reading a little bit on the `bulk_create` function I see some issues that apply to our model:
1) It does not work with child models in a multi-table inheritance scenario.
2) It does not work with many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Without knowing what the data, model or `create_profile` function looks like it's impossible to give an answer. If the bottleneck is the number of DB queries then using multiple processes will not help at all

Comment: use bulk create for it, so multy threading or processing on transactional DB is wrong way of think

Comment: I can't use bulk create because the model comes from an inherited table